# RestEasy client throwing exceptions

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I have a REST service where in case of bad authorisation, I return 401 and some error message.

Example if I use postman or other rest client, the response status is 401 and payload:

```
{
    "data": null,
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "REQUEST_NOT_AUTHORIZED",
            "message": "Request not authorized"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I use RestEasy client, then this exception is thrown automatically by the client:

```
EJB Invocation failed on component GatewayApi for method public com.example.AuthToken com.example.GatewayApi.authenticate(....): javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
```

If I try/catch the exception, then my payload is gone.

The way I am implementing is (for example):

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromPath(SERVICE_URL));
proxy = target.proxy(GatewayApiInterface.class);
```

**Later edit - auth method**

```
public AuthToken authenticate(String id, String name, String password) {
    try {
        ResponseEnvelope<AuthToken> authTokenResponseEnvelope = proxy.authenticate(id, name, password);
        return authTokenResponseEnvelope.getData();
    } catch (javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException wae) {
         return null;
    }
}
```

Is any way to stop RestEasy throwing exception every time status != 200?
Or some way to obtain my original payload from the Rest Server?

Comment: You may want to share com.example.GatewayApi.authenticate method to show us clear problem.

Comment: Hi, I added it the original post

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it :). This is a small test example that I used. Before I was not using Response (my bad)

**Server Side**

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
public Response test() {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
            .entity("TEST")
            .build();
}
```

**Client Side Proxy Class**

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Response test();
```

**Client**

```
Response response = proxy.test();
String test = response.readEntity(String.class);
System.out.println(test);
System.out.println(response.getStatus());
response.close();
```